# How to create a window placeholder in the dialog editor

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, dialog, atl

I apologize if I'm overlooking something, but I'm trying to just create a placeholder window within an ATL dialog, which will be used to host a preview handler.  I thought placing a custom control might be the thing to do, since it's blank and would occupy a designated place, but that's causing the dialog to crash, and I get the feeling doing something with a custom control is more complicated than I'm looking for.  So is there a way to just put a dummy window inside a dialog for use as a host site?  Thanks for any input.

Update: I seem to have achieved the desired result using a simple blank picture control.  But I'm still wondering if there's a more official way of doing this.

Comment: I generally use group controls (which is really just a style for the standard button class).

Answer (score 0):

for placeholder we need use exactly custom control. the point - need specify window class name. and this class must be registered.

let name of class will be *MyClass*

so in *.rc* file must be

```
CONTROL         "Custom1",IDC_CUSTOM1,"MyClass",...
```

and we need register *"MyClass"*, minimal code

```
class MyWndCls
{
    LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        switch (uMsg)
        {
        case WM_NCDESTROY:
            delete this;
            break;
        }

        return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    static LRESULT CALLBACK _WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<MyWndCls*>(GetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA))->WindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    static LRESULT CALLBACK StartWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        if (uMsg == WM_NCCREATE)
        {
            if (MyWndCls* p = new MyWndCls)
            {
                SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)p);
                SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)_WindowProc);
                return p->WindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
            }

            return 0;
        }

        return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    inline static const WCHAR clsname[] = L"MyClass";

public:

    static ULONG Register()
    {
        WNDCLASS wndcls = {
            0, StartWindowProc, 0, 0, (HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase, 0, 
            LoadCursorW(0, IDC_HAND), (HBRUSH)(COLOR_INFOBK + 1), 0, clsname 
        };
        return RegisterClassW(&wndcls) ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
    }

    static ULONG Unregister()
    {
        return UnregisterClassW(clsname, (HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase) ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
    }
};
```

of course we need call `MyWndCls::Register();` before create any dialog with this custom control